# Creating XML with LINQ in C#

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml, salesforce

I am trying to create the following XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jobInfo xmlns="http://www.force.com/2009/06/asyncapi/dataload">
<operation>insert</operation>
<object>Contact</object>
<contentType>CSV</contentType>
</jobInfo>
```

I have the following code (just starting out):

```
XElement _obj = new XElement("?xml",
                new XAttribute("version", "1.0"),
                new XAttribute("encoding", "UTF-8")
                );
```

The error I get is:

> Name cannot begin with the '?' character, hexadecimal value 0x3F.

I am new to creating XML with LINQ in C# and was just wondering if I am going about it the right way...  How can I create the XML document I am trying to create?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
XNamespace dl = "http://www.force.com/2009/06/asyncapi/dataload";
XElement jobInfo = new XElement(dl + "jobInfo",
  new XElement(dl + "operation", "insert"),
  new XElement(dl + "object", "Contact"),
  new XElement(dl + "contentType", "CSV")
);

jobInfo.Save("info.xml");
```

should do and write an XML declaration `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` without any need to create it explicitly.

Comment: What is `df` in this context?

Comment: Sorry, the XML uses a namespace and I wanted to show you to create/use that with C# and LINQ to XML. I declared the variable with name `dl` and then incorrectly used the name `df`. Now corrected.

Comment: Thanks, but this outputs everything except the first line `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`.  How can I get the first line in there?  (When I do `Console.WriteLine(jobInfo);`)

Comment: The XML declaration is added when you use the `Save` method, as I have shown. If you only use `ToString` as `Console.WriteLine(jobInfo)` would do then for an XElement you don't get an XML declaration. If you really think you want to explicitly create one then see the other answer and use an `XDocument doc = new XDocument(new XDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", null), new XElement(dl + "jobInfo", ... (same here as in answer)));`

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be looking for an [`XDeclaration`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdeclaration.aspx). These are automatically inserted, so you don't need to worry about them. If you really need it though:

```
XDeclaration _obj = new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "");
```

Comment: How can I use that with my existing code?  For instance, I am using Martin Honnen's code above.  How can I include the XDecalaration there?

Comment: @user You just need to include it in the first XElement constructor.